# plotting unit circle with custom arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles, aliasing

is it possible to plot this in latex? If not, could use some sugestions of alternate tools

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Yes, it is possible, but we are no do-it-for-me-service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am quite new to latex, not sure yet what I can or can't do. I just wanted to know if it is possible before I tried to actually do it, so I didn't tried nothing... Was thinking that I would have to do it with some other tool

Answer (score 4):

Two pictures in one.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=2]
  \newcommand\NumArrow{10}
  %% Coordinate system
  \draw[->](-1.3,0) -- (1.3,0);
  \draw[->](0,-1.3) -- (0,1.3);
  %% Unit circle
  \draw[thick] (0,0) circle(1);
  %% Arrows at \Num Arrow positions. \ang is the angle
  \foreach \ind [evaluate=\ind as \ang using {\ind*360/\NumArrow}] in {1,...,\NumArrow}{
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (\ang:1);
  }
  %% Draw small angles
  \foreach \ind [evaluate=\ind as \ang using {\ind*360/\NumArrow}] in {1,...,\NumArrow}{
    \draw[red,->] (\ang:0.3) arc (\ang:\ang+360/\NumArrow:0.3);
  }
  \draw[red,<-] (180/\NumArrow:0.3) -- (10:1.2) node[right]{$2\pi0.1$};
  %% Draw large angles
  \foreach \ind/\startR [evaluate=\ind as \ang using {\ind*360/\NumArrow}] in {0/0.7,1/0.6,2/0.5}{
    \draw[blue,->] [domain=0:360+360/\NumArrow,variable=\alpha,samples=50,smooth] plot (\alpha+\ang:\startR-\alpha/360*0.05);
  }
  \draw[blue,<-] (180/\NumArrow:0.7-0.025/\NumArrow) -- (20:1.2)  node[right]{$2\pi1.1$};;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this will be a real challenge to just understand because i am new to this, but I will spend some time trying to replicate alone, wasn't expecting such a complete answer, thanks!

Comment: @GustavoHiguchi, I have separated the parts and added some more color. The small angles (red) can be done with arc, which draws the circle segment between two angles. The large angles (blue) are trickier since they do not have the same radius in the beginning and end, so I did it as a plot.